# Fixed point of continuous mapping between punctured disk

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=B^2-\{a\}-\{b\}$, where $B^2$ is the unit disk on $\mathbb{R}^2$, $a, b$ are interior points of $B^2$. Is there a continuous map $f:X\rightarrow X$ which has no fixed point? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider an "$\infty$" curve $C$ in $B^2$ that goes around $a,b$. You can easily construct a map from  $B^2\setminus\{a,b\}$ to $C$ which fixes only the points of $C$.

Now map a "petal" of "C" to the other by a reflection. 
The only fixed points at this stage are those of the fixed petal.

Finally do a rotation on that petal. No fixed points remains.

Comment: This is nice. One comment: If the curve $C$ does not consist of two tangential (geometric) circles, one should note that the "rotation" must be more of a "slither" -- a sliding of the points along the pedal. That said, it makes me wonder if you can always choose circles of constant radius.